# How can I add date with another date in carbon laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

In my laravel project, I want to increase the date time with the previous date time.

Here is my code

```
$expire=$order[0]->expire_date;
$new=Carbon::now()->addMonths(6);
```

The results of these two lines are

```
2018-01-28 21:23:56
2018-06-28 21:43:29
```

What I want to do is sum the both dates.

```
$expire+$new
```

How can I achieve this? Any idea or thought? 
Thanks.

**Edit with more clear view**

I want to find the remaining days of the expire date from `now` and then want to add this remaining date with the new date. Hope it clears.

Comment: What do you mean by sum the dates?

Comment: What is the sum of two dates? What exactly do you expect to get if you add `2018-01-28 21:23:56` and `2018-06-28 21:43:29`?

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. Actually I want `2018-07-28 21:43:29` something like this. The new date should be added with the expire date.

Comment: So tell me where that expected `2018-07-28 21:43:29` comes from.... what is the relationship between that date and the other two dates? Do you simply want to add 1 month to $new?

Comment: Hi, I edited the question. Please if it helps now. And thank you so much!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to add six months to order expiration date, just do this:

```
$new = $order[0]->expire_date->addMonths(6);
```

This will work since `$order[0]->expire_date` is a Carbon instance.

If it's not, just parse it first:

```
$new = Carbon::parse($order[0]->expire_date)->addMonths(6);
```

Comment: Thanks just perfect. It gives me `2018-07-28 21:23:56` and by the way, this is what I tried too but I got error now it's working. May be some typo mistakes I did. 

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

you can add something like that:

```
$new=Carbon::createFromTimestamp($order[0]->expire_date->timestamp)->addMonths(6);
```

Comment: what is expire_date column? timestemp?

Comment: add in Order model if you didn't: protected $dates = ['expire_date'];

Comment: and with last changes?