# Addition of Carbon Dates in laravel php

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

I have two carbon dates and I would like to add the two together, how can I achieve this? I am using Laravel framework

```
$date1 = \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('H:i:s', $status_info->filed_ete)->addMinutes(15)

date two is in this variable of date_two
date_two = $status_info->filed_departuretime
```

how can i add date1 and date_two together, thank you

Comment: So what is your ' $status_info->filed_ete' value

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I add date with another date in carbon laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48014766/how-can-i-add-date-with-another-date-in-carbon-laravel)

Comment: What do you mean by adding two dates? You can add days to a date, but how would date adding work?

Comment: my filled_ete = 00:55:00 , my filed_departuretime = 1527440100 when converted to local time zone its Sunday, May 27, 2018 4:55:00, i would like to add the two inshort my fomular should be,     $expected_time = (filled_departuretime + filled_ete + 15 minutes)

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't make sense to add a date to another date (e.g. what does June 5th + July 4th equal?).

However, you can add a date *interval* to a date (or an interval to an interval).

In other words:

- Date + Date Interval = Date
- Date Interval + Date Interval = Date Interval
- Date + Date = doesn't make sense

So, basically, be careful about the which things are dates and which things are intervals. I'm guessing what you really mean is comparing two different dates to some reference date (like now).

Example with Carbon in Laravel:

```
// this is a date
// [now() is a Laravel helper that is the same as Carbon::now()]
$now = now();

// this is an interval
$departs_in_minutes = $now->diffInMinutes($departure_time);

// this is also an interval
$travel_minutes = $departure_time->diffInMinutes($arrival_time);

// this is adding an interval to a date
// which results in a date
$expected_time = now()->addMinutes($departs_in_minutes + $travel_minutes + 15);
```

See http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-difference

*Side note:* there is a "gotcha" with Carbon in that it is based on PHP's `DateTime` class and *not* `DateTimeImmutable`. So, you have to be careful when adding an interval to a date. It will add the interval to the original object, modifying it in the process, instead of returning a copy of that object as some might expect. To get around this, use the Carbon's `copy()` method when appropriate.